# I want to get sum of values of totals of different columns of different tables(i.e they are no linked through foreign keys) in one column or in query

Tags: ms-access

I want to get the sum value of total of Total_record field from employee_record tabel and Total field of Gazana_Mazdori table. I have many tables but to simplify my question I am only asking for two table Right now. These two tables are not linked with each other through foreign keys

***Gazana_Mazdoori*** table
[image]

***Employee Record*** table
[image]

My total value should be `75 (Total of Total_record field) + 550(total of Total field)=625`

Comment: Please do not add code as images; type it down in your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *union query* - lots of examples can be found by searching.

The official documentation is here:

[Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e)

Comment: can you please guide me in detail because when I am using union it is giving me crosstable not 1 value of sum of fields from different tabels

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub queries to get `Grand Total` from many table. Try below query-

```
SELECT GM.gmt+ER.ert as [Grand Total]
FROM 
(SELECT Sum(Gazana_Mazdori.Total) AS gmt FROM Gazana_Mazdori) as GM, 
(SELECT Sum(Employee_Record.Total_Record) AS ert FROM Employee_Record) as ER;
```

---

Get `Grand Total` from union query totals like below-

```
SELECT Sum(un.SumOfTotal) AS [Grand Total]
FROM 

(SELECT Sum(Employee_Record.Total_Record) AS SumOfTotal FROM Employee_Record
    UNION 
SELECT Sum(Gazana_Mazdori.Total) AS SumOfTotal FROM Gazana_Mazdori)  AS un;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to ask something more can I get sum of all entries of a field in another field of same table in access? If you can help me in this it will become very easy for me to complete my project

Comment: If yes then tell me how?

Comment: Yes, thats a very easier to achieve. You need to run a `UPDATE` query. Try `UPDATE Employee_Record SET Employee_Record.StoreTotal= DSum("Total_Record","Employee_Record")`

Comment: If you found the answer helpful please mark it as answered. Tick mark it. Also upvote encourage visitors.